# Use array_filter() to return two arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm consuming a web service that returns an array of objects called `$viewData` like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 64757
            [title] => Frogger
            [votes] => 1
            [status] => gotit
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 64758
            [title] => The Legend of Zelda
            [votes] => 1
            [status] => wantit
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 64759
            [title] => Grand Theft Auto
            [votes] => 1
            [status] => wantit
        )

)
```

I need to split this into two separate arrays - one that contains all the objects whose status is wantit, and the other whose status is gotit.

I can get one array out of it by using `array_filter()` with a custom function:

```
if(is_array($viewData) and (!empty($viewData))) {
    function splitGames($v){
        if ($v->status==="gotit") {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    $gotEm = array_filter($viewData, "splitGames");
    print_r($gotEm);

}
```

This function returns what I'd expect:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 64757
            [title] => Frogger
            [votes] => 1
            [status] => gotit
        )
)
```

Is there a way to automatically get what's left of the original array into a second array, or do I need to have a second custom function that looks for a status of "wantit" and rerun `array_filter()` again on the original array?

Comment: array_filter returns only a single array. you cannot have it return multiple arrays in a single call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need two arrays, you will need to call `array_filter` twice.

Alternatively, you could start with two empty arrays and just loop once over `$viewData`, placing each array member into one of the two arrays based upon the `status` value.

Does that help?

Comment: Yeah, I knew I could loop like that; I was just hoping to find something more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use array_walk.

```
$wantit = array();
$gotit = array();


function wantitorgetit($arr, $key, $arrs)
{


 if ($arr->status=='wantit')
    {

       $arrs[0][]=$arr;
    }
 else
  {
     $arrs[1][] =$arr; 
  }

}




$arrs = array(&$wantit,&$gotit);
array_walk($Viewdata, 'wantitorgetit', $arrs);

print_r($wantit);
print_r($gotit);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$wantit = [];
$gotit = [];

array_filter($viewData, function ($item) use (&$wantit, &$gotit) {
if ($item['status'] == "wantit") {
    $wantit[] = $item;
} else {
    $gotit[] = $item;
}
return true;
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this command may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this 
code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)